# How do Blue potatoes differ from Yukon Gold potatoes?

Tags: substitutions, potatoes

In what ways do Blue potatoes differ from Yukon Golds?  (Other than the color.)

- Do they have comparable amounts of starch and water?
- Do they have a different flavor or texture?
- How should I be prepared adjust my cooking method if substituting Blues for Yukons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experiment, blue potatoes were substitutable for Yukon Golds.  However:

- Blue potatoes are smaller than Yukon Golds.  Therefore, cooking time should be lessened by a between half to a third, particularly when parboiling.
- Rather than having the subtle creamy flavor of Yukons, Blue potatoes have a distinctly nutty flavor.  This flavor may drown out more subtle flavors that are common to recipes calling for Yukon Golds.

Comment: Great follow-through!

Answer (score 5):

There definitely is a difference in flavor, although it is rather subtle. I find that the blue potatoes are a touch richer or more "potato-y" than Yukon Golds. However, in cooking with them I've had plenty of success doing direct substitutions. Other than the blue color being a little odd-looking in some recipes I think you'd be safe just swapping one for the other in most cases.